# I need to look up a filename based on userinput and then read out the file contents

Tags: bash

I need to look up a filename based on userinput and then read out the file, however this only works for the first file in the directory, not for the others, please help!

Here's my .sh file so far

```
#!/bin/bash
dir="test_users"
echo "Please enter filename"
read filename
find . -name "$filename" 
cat $filename
if [ "$?" -ne 0 ] 
then
    echo "file: $filename does not exist"
fi
```

Comment: You should put `"$filename"` in quotes to ensure funny characters entered by the user don't break your program. What is the `find` command for? What doesn't work with the other files - is there an error message, do you get unexpected output, ...? Can you provide an example with a directory and two short text files?

Comment: To test for the existence of a file, don't use `cat` but `if [ -f "$filename" ]; then cat "$filename"; else echo "$filename doesn't exist"; fi`

Comment: I have three .usr files inside the test_users directory: Izaiah_Ceres.usr John_Hopkins.usr and Max_Power.usr all of the files have the full name, user ID and job code inside. The first file prints out perfectly fine with this output: Izaiah Ceres
123456
AA99
234567, but when I test on the other 2 files, I get cat: Max_Power.usr: No such file or directory

Comment: I just tested your script. It works. What happens when you provide `John_Hopkins.usr` as input? Also, what is the purpose of the line `dir="test_users"`?

Comment: Sorry I'm still learning bash in uni, I put that line there to make sure it searches in the test_users directory folder. When I put John_Hopkins.usr as an input I get: "file: John_Hopkins.usr does not exist" yet it is there and I can open it and verify that the contents in the file is normal, even if I just run a simple "cat John_Hopkins.usr" the file is read correctly

Comment: Is "John_Hopkins.usr does not exist" the only message? I would have expected an error message from the `cat` command. In any case, it means that the `cat` command failed somehow. It could be because the current directory contains no file named `John_Hopkins.usr`, or because the file is not readable (permissions problem?), or there might be other problems with the `cat` command. Check the presence of this file and its permissions by typing `ls -l`.

Comment: The line `dir="test_users"` just sets a variable named `dir` to the value `test_users`. It has no other effect on your script. Likewise, the `find` command in your script finds a file with that name in the current directory and all subdirectories (if any), but has no other effect on the script.

Comment: -rwxrw-r--+ 1 izaia izaia 32 Feb  6 18:05 Izaiah_Ceres.usr
-rwxrw-r--+ 1 izaia izaia 32 Feb  7 20:01 John_Hopkins.usr
-rwxrw-r--+ 1 izaia izaia 29 Feb  7 20:01 Max_Power.usr The permissions don't seem to be an issue

Comment: The + sign next to the permissions indicates that the files have ACLs. They might prevent you from reading them. In any case, what happens when you run `cat John_Hopkins.usr` at the command prompt? And are you sure that there is no error message from `cat` when you run the script?

Comment: Again, rather than using `cat` to test for the presence of a file, use `if [ -f ...]`. Actually, better `if [ -r ... ]`, since that tests whether the file is readable.

Comment: What do you mean by "this only works for the first file in the directory"? Are you able to `cat` the first file, but not the other two? I thought your script only printed the contents of a single file. Do you mean you ran your script three separate times, once for each of the three files?

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with `cat`'s error message if the file cannot be read, the script is very simple:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
printf "Please enter filename: "
read -r filename
cat "$filename"
```

If you want to output your own error message if the file cannot be read, you can do this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
printf "Please enter filename: "
read -r filename

if [ -r "$filename" ]; then
    # File is readable, so print contents
    cat "$filename"
elif [ -f "$filename" ]; then
    # File exists, but file cannot be read
    echo "Cannot read file $filename."
else
    # File does not exist
    echo "File $filename does not exist."
fi
```